# Retrieving the protocol of a socket in winsock

Tags: sockets, network-programming, winsock, network-protocols

I am working in networking reliability simulation, I need to simulate packet dropping based on a quality of service percentage. Currently I have a DLL that hooks into `send`, `sendto`, `recv` and `recvfrom`. My hooks then 'drop' packets based on the quality of service.

I just need to apply the hook to UDP packets, and not disturb TCP (TCP is used for remote debugging).

Is there a way that I can query WinSock for the protocol that a socket is bound to?

```
int WSAAPI HookedSend(SOCKET s, const char FAR * buf, int len, int flags)
{
  //if(s is UDP)
  //Drop according to QOS

  else
    //Send TCP packets undisturbed
    return send(s, buf, len, flags);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could get the socket type by using `getsockopt`:

```
int optVal;
int optLen = sizeof(int);

getsockopt(socket, 
          SOL_SOCKET, 
          SO_TYPE, 
          (char*)&optVal, 
          &optLen);

if(optVal = SOCK_STREAM)
     printf("This is a TCP socket.\n");
else if(optVal = SOCK_DGRAM)
     printf("This is a UTP socket.\n");
else
     printf("Error");
```

Comment: Found in getsockopt documentation that the option SO_BSP_STATE returns addres, port, and protocol. Thank you